# How to round the column mean to integer in a dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to round off the mean value of the column "Age" to integer with the following code,

```
df['Age'].mean().round()
```

but I get this error,

> 'float' object has no attribute 'round'.

Comment: `round(df[...]...)` - https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
df['Age'].mean().round(0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because scalar is returned from `df['Age'].mean()`, use [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Age':[10, 20, 34]})

print (df['Age'].mean())
21.333333333333332

print (round(df['Age'].mean()))
21

print (round(df['Age'].mean(), 3))
21.333
```

Comment: What was the need of downvoting my answer?

Comment: hmmm, there is no reason for it?

Comment: @MayankPorwal - Why do you think so?

Comment: No. I am kindly asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211724/discussion-between-jezrael-and-mayank-porwal).

Comment: @ansev - One element Series? I think rather not.

Comment: @ansev - I think here is mistake. In pandas are obviosly used arrays, series, df, but scalars very rare. So `.round()` is used by OP.

Answer (score 0):

I found this to work nicely. Should bypass the error and give expected output all in one line of code:

`int(round(df['column'].mean(),0))`

Comment: There is no need for this. As you can see in jezrael's answer, if you omit the second (ndigits) argument to the `round` function, the return value automatically becomes an integer.